# Show Feed in two columns in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, feed

So I have a blog post feed. I want the feed to appear in my homepage, in two columns.

```
-----------------------
Recent     | 4th Recent
2nd Recent | 5th Recent
3rd Recent | 6th Recent
-----------------------
```

I am using Material Design, from http://materializecss.com, and got the feed successfully.
The problem is just to align it into two columns.

Here is the HTML code that allowed me to display the items in a single column.

```
<table id="blogPostTable"><tbody id="blogPostBody"></tbody></table>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.foxinflame.tk/blog/feed/",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        var description = $(this).find("description").text();
        var comments = +($(this).find("slash:comments").text());
        var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();
        $("#blogPostTable").append("<tr class=\"blogpostTR\"><td class=\"z-depth-1 blogpost\"><h5>"+title+"</h5><p>"+description+"<br><i>"+comments+" Comments. Published "+pubDate+"</i></p></td></tr>");
      });
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

And here is the CSS

```
#blogPostTable {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}
.blogpost {
  color: black;
  background-color: #dedede;
}
.blogpostTR:nth-child(n+4){
  display:none;
}
```

The CSS allows me to display up to only 3, because too much will just clutter.

So with my current JavaScript, it generates a TR and one TD inside it for each blogpost. If I add another TD element in it, the order of the grid will be different.

Now, how do I make it into 2 columns, with the specified order? I guess I should start with the CSS, changing the nth-child to 7...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to make a row like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6"></div>
    <div class="col s6"></div>
</div>
```

and then fill the columns with the posts. Keep adding posts to the first column and when it's full start filling the second. If you have ten posts and want to put five in the first an easy way would be to add a counter in the success function and append to column 1 if < 5 and column 2 otherwise.

(Haven't used materialize so not sure if s6 is correct class or if you need someting else but the idea is to split into 2 columns each 6 grid cols wide.)

THen you can get rid of the table also, but this won't work if you need the posts to align vertically also.

Comment: Worked. Amazing! I changed the `each(function(){...})` to  `each(function(eachCounter){if(eachCounter > 2 {] else {] ...})`

Answer (score -2):

If you can use CSS3, then there is a function to split paragraph in a way you need.

The best and cleanest way would be structure something like this:

```
<div id="collection">
    <div>title,description,comments</div>
    ....
    </div>
```

and based on example of w3schools apply that rule to id collection. Tables won't work.